# Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. ionic 3 please helpp

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic3

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 10.277 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznv;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznv;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877434/android-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-android-gms-common-api-zza)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `platforms/android` and open `build.gradle`.

Then add `multiDexEnabled true` to `defaultConfig`.

It should look like this at the end :

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
    applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

    if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
        minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
    }

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**EDIT**

You might have a different issue after this. I suggest you to clean your project by removing every platforms, the `/platforms` and `/plugins` folders, and then reinstall everything.

Comment: u saved my life <3

Comment: HI, I am also doing same thing but still facing same issue (Using IONIC 4).